# PHP - find string cointaining semicolon with strpos() fails

Tags: php, strpos

I have a string like

```
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20190208
```

and I want to use the PHP function strpos() to find

```
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:
```

this works only if I remove the semicolon

I tried

```
if(strpos($subValue, "DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:")){
```

and also with (1, 2, 3 times) escaping the semicolon

```
strpos($subValue, "DTSTART\;VALUE=DATE:")
strpos($subValue, "DTSTART\\;VALUE=DATE:")
strpos($subValue, "DTSTART\\\;VALUE=DATE:")
```

I tried stripos() and also single quotes instead of double quotes, no success.

Any idea ?

Comment: `$subValue` = `DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20190208`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strpos` will return 0 because needle is found in position 0, and 0 is `false` value that why you have to use value and the data type comparison (===)

```
if (strpos($subValue, 'DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:') !== false) {
```

Comment: Also, please dont just post code some code. We prefer an explnation *why* you have that piece of code :)

Comment: @NicoHaase Martijn, sorry I was doing the update, now I've updated it.

Answer (score 1):

The code is working fine.

`strpos` will return `0` is this case. Which will be treated as `false`.

Try -

```
if(strpos($subValue, "DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:") !== false) {
```

Comment: @Martijn `DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:` to be searched  in `DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20190208`.

Comment: Hmm. Happens sometimes.